# more columns with select

Tags: mysql, sql

The question is a little crazy. 
I have a table in MySQL with columns 'id', 'from' and 'to'. 
I want the select to perform on this table and I need more columns for subsequent tasks.

An example:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS bla;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE bla (SELECT *, (SELECT id) AS test FROM flug WHERE flug_id >= 1 AND flug_id < 11);
UPDATE bla SET test = 100000;
SELECT flug_id, test FROM bla;
```

Are there other ways to create further columns?

With best regards

Stephan

Comment: You mean you want to have more columns in the table? `alter` table and  `add column`

Comment: I am still confused with the question!

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just do?

```
SELECT flug_id, 100000 as test 
FROM flug as f
WHERE flug_id >= 1 
  AND flug_id < 11;
```